# How to save c# (asp.net core) datetime to PostgreSQL date

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, npgsql

I am using the npgsql package to pass parameters to a postgresql function. But I am getting exception saying that a function with the specified number/type of arguments is not defined. I went throught the trouble of testing all the parameters and I am sure the one that is causing the problem is the c# datetime parameters that is passed to a postgresql date data type.

I orginally tried this:

```
  //here BirthDate is Datetime, as it doesn't seem
   // to have another built-in date type in asp.net core
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birth_date", cliente.BirthDate);
```

I read some post here in SO and they said that using the property Date would solve but it didn't work for me.

```
  //doesn't work either
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birth_date", cliente.BirthDate.Date);
```

Comment: Someone posted a comment but removed it, it said for me to use cmd.Parameters.Add() and it worked.  cmd.Parameters.Add("@birth_date", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Date, 20).Value = cliente.BirthDate.Date;

Comment: You should add that as an answer, then.

Answer (score 2):

NpgSql's `AddWithValue` does its best to map the datatype of the C# property to the PostgreSQL field's datatype, but the issue is that PostgreSQL has two primary datatypes for date:

`date`
`timestamp`

But C# has just the one -- `System.DateTime`.  So even the `.Date` Property of a `DateTime` object yields a `DateTime` type.

In other words, NpgSql has to make a choice -- and it renders the PostgreSQL datatype as a timestamp.  If your DB type is actually a date, the execution will fail due to datatype mismatch.

For strings, integers, decimals and doubles `AddWithValue` always seems to work exactly as expected, but if your date is a [PostgreSQL] DATE then you need to be explicit with your parameter declaration's datatype.  In general, this is a good practice anyway:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@birth_date", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Date));
cmd.Parameters[0].Value = cliente.BirthDate;
```

This is definitely advantageous over `AddWithValue` if you are doing multiple transactions like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@birth_date", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Date));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@user_id", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer));

foreach (User u in Users)
{
    cmd.Parameters[0].Value = u.Birthday;
    cmd.Parameters[1].Value = u.UserId;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

For a single query or transaction, you can also use the Shorthand:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@birth_date", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Date)).
    Value = cliente.BirthDate;
```

As a final alternative, you can "fix" the dbtype after the fact:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birth_date", cliente.BirthDate);
cmd.Parameters[0].NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Date;
```

I don't think that's any easier than the other options, but it is an option that will work.