Npgsql COUNT query returns 0 even though data exists with matching date and EmployeeId in PostgreSQL
I have a code that checks if a record exists:
  using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();
                
                var query = @"
                SELECT COUNT(1)
               FROM TimeEntries
                  WHERE EmployeeId = @EmployeeId AND Date::date = @Date";
                
                using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId", timeEntry.EmployeeId);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", timeEntry.Date.Date);  
                    
                    var count = (long)await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();

                    if (count > 0)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("Pracownik już ma zarejestrowane godziny pracy w tej dacie.");
                    }
                }

and i send there request like:
{
  "date": "2024-12-29T21:42:58.251Z",
  "hoursWorked": 0
}

and id in a query.
The problem is that it doesnt work.
The data in a table are as follow:
"id"    "employeeid"    "date"  "hoursworked"
7             2       "2024-12-29"      8.00

I thought it doesnt work because here:
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", timeEntry.Date.Date);  

the value of a parameter is 29.12.2024 00:00:00 instead of 29.12.2024 but the sql query:
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM TimeEntries
WHERE EmployeeId = 2 AND Date::date = '2024-12-29 00:00:00';

return the proper value of 10, but in code the count is always 0...
It works with:
   var data = new DateTime(timeEntry.Date.Year, timeEntry.Date.Month, 
timeEntry.Date.Day, 0, 0, 0);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId", timeEntry.EmployeeId);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", data);  

but still i dont understand why previous version didnt work...

Run the code in the debugger. In the debugger, check the values of all of the properties of timeEntry (using the Immediate Window or Watch Window) and include those in the question. Do not guess what the values are. Use the debugger.

Please share a [mcve].

the values i have written are from debugger

I'd suggest being explicit about which date type you want - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49086150/34092 .

Please show us the CREATE TABLE script for TimeEntries .

Any time zones in these dates being passed around? Remove the date parameter from the query and download all the rows for the employee. Do you see the row you're expecting? Does c# consider your date parameter and the row date as equal?

Are you 100% sure you are connected to the correct database?

What is the value of timeEntry.Date.Date.Kind

@Charlieface is likely correct here. The difference between your working and your non-working code is likely the Kind of the relevant DateTime.

Please share us the definition of your TimeEntry class.

The request you're sending shows a timestamptz-type value. Even if you cast the Date column to a ::date explicitly like you did, comparing it to a timestamptz will not make Postgres pick a date = date operator and autocast timestamptz::date on the right to match the left operand, truncating away anything below days, if that's what you wanted.
My initial guess was that you're seeing Postgres use type preference in pg_type.typispreferred to pick the best = operator candidate, casting the date on the left to a timestamptz that is the preference in the 'D' type group it shares with date and arriving at timestamptz = timestamptz rather than date = date. As it turns out, there's a date = timestamptz already, so that's not necessary:
demo at db<>fiddle
select oid::regoperator
      ,oprname
      ,oprleft::regtype
      ,oprright::regtype
      ,oprresult::regtype
      ,oprcode
from pg_operator
where oprname='='
and oprleft='date'::regtype;




oid
oprname
oprleft
oprright
oprresult
oprcode




=(date,date)
=
date
date
boolean
date_eq


=(date,timestamp without time zone)
=
date
timestamp without time zone
boolean
date_eq_timestamp


=(date,timestamp with time zone)
=
date
timestamp with time zone
boolean
date_eq_timestamptz



10.2. Operators describes the type conversion rules that apply here and this case gets resolved before reaching step 3.d. What you're seeing is the timestamptz you send as @Date gets shifted according to your TimeZone before the comparison:
set timezone='US/Pacific';

select '2024-12-29 00:00:00Z'::date
     = '2024-12-29 00:00:00Z'::timestamptz;









False



You can use explain verbose to see what Postgres did to the value before running the query:
explain verbose
select '2024-12-29 00:00:00Z'::date
     = '2024-12-29 00:00:00Z'::timestamptz




QUERY PLAN




Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=1)


Output: ('2024-12-29'::date = '2024-12-28 16:00:00-08'::timestamp with time zone)



Make sure timeEntry.Date.Date gets sent as a PostgreSQL type date, or adjust your session's TimeZone setting if it's supposed to match those rows. Your 2024-12-29T21:42:58.251Z is close enough to midnight that any zone east of +03:00 will see it as 2024-12-30. Also, your clients in different time zones get different values for Date::date if that column is also a timestamptz:
create table timeentries("date")as values
 ('2024-12-29 21:00:00+00'::timestamptz)
,('2024-12-29 20:59:59.999999+00')
,('2024-12-30 02:59:59.999999+00')
,('2024-12-30 03:00:00+00');

set timezone='UTC';
select date
      ,date::date as "::date" 
from timeentries;




date
::date




2024-12-29 21:00:00+00
2024-12-29


2024-12-29 20:59:59.999999+00
2024-12-29


2024-12-30 02:59:59.999999+00
2024-12-30


2024-12-30 03:00:00+00
2024-12-30



set timezone='UTC+03';
select date
      ,date::date as "::date" 
from timeentries;




date
::date




2024-12-29 18:00:00-03
2024-12-29


2024-12-29 17:59:59.999999-03
2024-12-29


2024-12-29 23:59:59.999999-03
2024-12-29


2024-12-30 00:00:00-03
2024-12-30



set timezone='UTC-03';
select date
      ,date::date as "::date" 
from timeentries;




date
::date




2024-12-30 00:00:00+03
2024-12-30


2024-12-29 23:59:59.999999+03
2024-12-29


2024-12-30 05:59:59.999999+03
2024-12-30


2024-12-30 06:00:00+03
2024-12-30



